# LinearModelFit to find more than one linear regression line

Tags: functions, fitting

I have a data that I used `LinearModelFit`, to find the linear regression line. How can I get more than one linearmodelfit for the same data? more specifically  I want 3 different functions for the linear regression with the built-in function `LinearModelFit`.

Here is the data :

```
{{"Weight(lbs)", "Length(in)"}, {83, 86}, {70, 88}, {61, 72}, {54, 74}, {44, 61}, {106, 90}, {84, 89}, {39, 68}, {42, 76}, {197, 114}, {102, 90}, {57, 78}, {130, 94}, {51, 74}, {640, 147}, {28, 58}, {80, 86}, {110, 94}, {33, 63}, {90, 86}, {36, 69}, {38, 72}, {366, 128}, {84, 85}, {80, 82}}
```

Comment: Would you give an example?  It sounds like you just need to write 3 different `LinearModelFit` statements.

Comment: Here is the data : {{"Weight(lbs)", "Length(in)"}, {83, 86}, {70, 88}, {61, 72}, {54, 
  74}, {44, 61}, {106, 90}, {84, 89}, {39, 68}, {42, 76}, {197, 
  114}, {102, 90}, {57, 78}, {130, 94}, {51, 74}, {640, 147}, {28, 
  58}, {80, 86}, {110, 94}, {33, 63}, {90, 86}, {36, 69}, {38, 
  72}, {366, 128}, {84, 85}, {80, 82}}

Comment: Choose three different functions for the
linear regression with the build-in function LinearModelFit and compare
the results.  and here is what Im trying to solve

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Do you mean like `lm1 = LinearModelFit[data, {x}, {x}]`
and
`lm2 = LinearModelFit[data, {Log[x]}, {x}]`
and
`lm3 = LinearModelFit[data, {Exp[x]}, {x}]`?

Answer (score 2):

You could modify the `Weights` inside `LinearModelFit` to get different regression results:

```
data = {{83, 86}, {70, 88}, {61, 72}, {54, 74}, {44, 61}, {106, 90}, {84, 89}, {39, 68}, {42, 76}, {197, 114}, {102, 90}, {57,78}, {130, 94}, {51, 74}, {640, 147}, {28, 58}, {80, 86}, {110, 94}, {33, 63}, {90, 86}, {36, 69}, {38, 72}, {366, 128}, {84,85}, {80, 82}};

lm1 = LinearModelFit[data, x, x]
lm2 = LinearModelFit[data, x, x, Weights -> 1/data[[All, 2]]]
lm3 = LinearModelFit[data, x, x, Weights -> data[[All, 1]]]

Show[{ListPlot[data], Plot[{lm1[x], lm2[x], lm3[x]}, {x, 0, 200}]}]
```

[image]